# Setting file extension for File Dialog in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, file-extension, filedialog

I was wondering how to set the file extension for a file dialog so that only those files with that extension show up in the folder.  I know there is a way to set if files/directories can be seen, and the folder that the file dialog looks in, but haven't come across a way to set the file extension.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the NSOpenPanel/NSSavePanel method `setAllowedFileTypes:`. OS X thinks in terms of file types, not extensions.

Comment: that for some reason was not working but i did end up finding that runModalForTypes: worked instead. thanks for your input!